# angular.copy not breaking reference to array properties

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I need to copy an object and perform some filtering before sending it to the server. In this instance, I need to remove two array properties. However, when I delete the array properties from the copied object, they are removed from the original as well. What's correct method to use to remove the references?

```
// Copy object to master for use as a backup
$scope.master = angular.copy($scope.user); 

    return $http( {method: 'PUT',
        url: config.serviceBaseUri_v3 + $rootScope.permissions.PutUsers.uri.replace("{userId}", data.id),
        data: $.param(filterPutRequest(angular.copy(data))),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}});

    // Remove unwanted properties from the server request
    var filterPutRequest = function(user){
        if($rootScope.permissions.PutUsers.fields){
            var propNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(user);
            for(var i=0;i<propNames.length;i++){
                if($rootScope.permissions.PutUsers.fields.indexOf(propNames[i]) === -1){
                    delete user[propNames[i]];
                }
            }
        }
        return user;
    };
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this, can you post something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/T1fiHwpeHU5puP8257GO?p=info) to demonstrate what you are actually trying to do.